# Spring production ready authentication with OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm looking for help in choosing the right, most modern and safest way to authenticate. I'm using Spring as backend along with Angular on frontend. I'll add that I want to use OAuth2. I've really searched quite a few sites and haven't found a straight answer. I'm really confused...

I started with [this implementation](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/), but than I stopped after reading [this recommendations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-16). So far I know that I should use Authorization Code Grant with PKCE.

How is it done in applications that are already in production?
The most sensible (as I think) option so far is implementing auth with Keycloak. Is [embedded version](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app) reliable?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure your API with OAuth there are many products out there which you can use (both open-source and paid solutions, if you search for "identity server" you should be able to find a few solutions). Keycloak is a viable option, but there are others.

When it comes to choosing a flow, I would also go with the Authorization Code Grant with PKCE. This currently is the recommended way, especially if you'll be performing OAuth flows directly from your Angular app.

That's another decision you would have to make - whether you want your frontend client contact the Authorization Server directly (then you have to handle tokens in the frontend app), or you want to call your backend and have the backend talk to the Authorization Server (then you would probably have a session cookie, and associate the session with any access tokens).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know that there are some other products than Keycloak. I chose this one bearing in mind that it is free.

I think that the best option is to login with flow like: Angular <-> Spring <-> Keycloak <-> Auth Server

Comment: Authentication is new topic for me and I don't want to mess anything up.

As far as I understand: firstly I should install Keycloak, than use adapter in Spring Application. Keycloak will handle authentication with PKCE for me and return access token to my Spring App, than I should return token to Angular app and use it to authenticate in my app or maybe I should generate new one valid only in my app...?

Comment: In this setup which you describe PKCE will happen between Spring and Keycloak. Spring will have to generate the code challenge and Keycloak will subsequently verify it when issuing tokens. As for the access token - it's up to you whether you send the access token from Keycloak to Angular, or create session / different token.